# What is the difference between 撒谎 and 说谎?

Tags: meaning, difference

As far as I know, 撒谎 and 说谎 have the same meaning of "telling a lie". Is there a difference between them?

Comment: *我没有说谎 我何必说谎/爱一个人 没爱到难道就会怎麼样 /别说我说谎 人生已经如此地艰难 /有些事情 就不要拆穿* OP could liseten to the song **说谎**  to get a better feeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion,

1. 说谎 can be used in the case of telling white lies; 撒谎 usually means telling malicious lies just to cheat someone.
2. 说谎 is inclined to telling meticulously prepared lies; 撒谎 in inclined to telling casual lies.
3. 说谎 is more formal; 撒谎 is used in spoken language more.

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting to look at the usage of the verbs for lies. 说 means say, so literally say a lie. But 撒 means throw，so "throw"  a lie indicates the lie teller is throwing the lie from the distance, which means he or she can not face to the listener(s) too close because of the guilty.

Answer (score 0):

There is no essential difference between them and usually they are interchangeable.

May be this is not a good analogy, but:

think about "撒尿", which means piss.

1. We do it everyday.
2. We are accustomed to it.

My impression is that 撒谎 applies more to children, while for adult, 说谎 is inclined to telling meticulously prepared lies (quoted from songyuanyao's comment).